# Why does ATC ask a crew who has declared an emergency if their aircraft will be overweight when landing?

Tags: air-traffic-control, landing, emergency

I have heard ATC ask an emergency aircraft if they will be overweight when landing.
Why do they ask?
I am not asking about the consequences of an overweight landing or what procedures are required following one, but rather why ATC would ask for this in advance of the landing.

E.G.

- Does ATC take it into account when offering a runway?
- Does passing it on to emergency services somehow allow them to be better prepared than if they were informed after the fact?

Comment: Higher possibility of a brake fire or runway overrun is one of the reasons.

Comment: Besides, landing a highly loaded aircraft is not advisable, since –apart from the reasons stated above– a tire (or more) may easily burst if the high-speed contact is hard, and that will be a serious extra complication...

Comment: They want to know because of the consequences of an overweight landing, but you said you didn't want to know about that.

Comment: The brakes are designed for a certain amount of energy and it doesn't matter much how long time it takes for that amount of energy to be dumped into the brakes (time is too short for any significant amount of heat to transfer to air). So, unless you give it a ultra long runway, e.g. 10 minutes of deceleration time, the brake will overheat no matter what. The best ATC can do is probably to assign a clear runway so when the plane loses control after the brake overheats and blows a tire or two it won't hit anything on the ground.

Comment: @OrangeDog sorry I wasn't sufficiently clear  -  A separate question asked what are the consequences which I didn't want to duplicate.  My question was was one of timing - why ATC would want to know ahead of the landing as opposed to checking after the fact..  Answers in the other question didn't seem to indicate that knowing ahead of time would matter.

Comment: Knowing the fact after the landing seems a little superfluous; to late to use the information for improving the chances for a successfull landing.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If an aircraft encounters a serious problem quite soon after departure that forces it to land immediately, the aircraft may be above its certified maximum landing weight. This is because there is still a lot of fuel in the tanks, which adds a lot of weight.

As @RonBeyer mentioned in a comment, landing overweight can have a number of serious consequences. When landing a heavy aircraft, stopping it on the runway already requires a lot of energy (or rather, a lot of energy needs to be converted into something else). If the aircraft is heavier than it is designed to be on landing, this may cause excessive stress on the brakes. In extreme cases, this can make the brakes catch fire. Now, open flames under an aircraft that is almost fully loaded with fuel is the recipe for disaster.

In some cases, even though the crew brakes hard on landing, the aircraft may be so heavy that stopping on the runway is impossible. A runway excursion will then follow (a situation where the aircraft leaves the runway onto the grass or similar). This is not neccesarily dangerous, but it certainly can be, depending on the surrounding terrain:

[image]

(image from http://avherald.com/h?article=46f3d531. This aircraft was not overweight, but I still think the situation shown in the picture is relevant to this question.)

Obviously, in an emergency ATC, and in turn the fire and rescue crew at the airport, need to be prepared for such events. If ATC expects an aircraft will be landing overweight, getting the crew to confirm this will allow ATC to inform the fire crew that they can expect brake fires or a potential runway excursion. It can also enable the rescue leader to position the fire vehicles at the best possible position, which would be further down the runway than normal, since the landing roll will be longer. So basically, it's a way to get information to the rescue crew so that they can prepare for what might be coming.

Depending on the type of emergency, ATC will also ask the crew about other details, in some cases also with the purpose of passing this information on to the rescue crew, since the rescue crew will normally not be in direct contact with the cockpit as long as the plane is in the air. See also this related question: [Why does ATC ask emergency aircraft about fuel on board?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42902/why-does-atc-ask-emergency-aircraft-about-fuel-on-board)

Comment: And even if everything goes well, the brakes will be hotter than normal, which means the aircraft may need to wait a bit for them to cool down before it can taxi to the stand. Maybe even on the runway. At the very least, the ground controller will need to find a parking space for them near the runway, where they can let the brakes cool down. Worst case, they need to be towed from the runway.

Comment: So why doesn't ATC ask "are you going to crash-land, and if so how?"  or something :P  Or is the idea to offload that part of the planning from the pilots?  If so, there must be other questions about what kind of ground support might be needed.

Comment: @PeterCordes "Are you overweight" is a much simpler question, with a much simpler answer, than "Are you going to crash land and if so, how?" In an emergency, the pilot(s) doesn't want to deal with anything that's not necessary, so simple questions are preferred when information is needed to coordinate activities on the ground. ATC has a whole bunch of people who can take that simple information and formulate a rescue plan without burdening the pilot(s).

Comment: AFACT, emergency vehicles are *always* positioned near the *approach* end of the runway and *chase* the aircraft. This is to minimize the risk that the aircraft collides with the vehicles (in case it has lateral runway excursion).

Answer (score 31):

To add to the other answer, a great example of needing to burn off fuel before attempting an emergency landing was [JetBlue 292](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBlue_Flight_292). The nose gear would not retract after takeoff and, after flying by the tower to get a visual, they determined the nose gear was stuck in a twisted way. The flight had to circle for 2 hours to burn off fuel before landing, since it was obvious the landing gear would be damaged upon doing so.

[image]

> The pilots flew the aircraft, which can carry up to 46,860 pounds (21,255 kg) of aviation fuel, in a figure eight pattern between Bob Hope Airport in Burbank and LAX for more than two hours in order to burn fuel and lower the risk of fire upon landing. This also served to lighten the plane, reducing potential stress on the landing gear and dramatically lowering landing speed as well. The Airbus A320 does not have the mechanical facility to dump fuel, despite various news agencies reporting that the aircraft was doing so over the ocean.

Comment: _"The Airbus A320 does not have the mechanical facility to dump fuel, despite various news agencies reporting that the aircraft was doing so over the ocean."_ - excellent example of how a lot of aviation related stuff is misreported in mass media.

Comment: Wow, I can't imagine having to announce to the cabin, "We're going to have an emergency landing in about 2 hours.  Just sit tight, nothing to be worried about.  (There will be plenty to worry about when we actually try to land)"

Comment: @CortAmmon It was even worse. They had satellite TV so they could watch TV news commentators talk about the plane they were stuck on. And you know how they love worst-case scenarios...

Comment: Would it have made sense for them to fly towards New York (the intended destination)?  Having the nose gear stuck down would increase drag, so they'd probably want to aim for a landing part way there, but they could at least put the fuel to good use instead of just wasting it.  Hmm, I guess if they can't make it to New York, it's probably less convenient to deal with the passengers, and they need to burden a new airport with their problem.

Comment: As a side note, most military aircraft have the ability to manually initiate a 'fuel-dump' letting them pump excess fuel out of the tanks before attempting a landing when seriously overweight.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't see any advantage to that.  LAX is a major airport; which would make finding alternate routing for the affected passgeners much easier than whatever small location they ended up at. If something did go horribly wrong on landing, again LAX is presumably better equiped to handle it and has access to major trauma centers to treat the injured.  The same is true for access to repair facilities.  A middle of nowhere airport would be worse in almost every possible way.

Comment: @DanNeely: I was imagining they'd pick a large airport maybe half way or 3/4 of the way to NYC; one they were sure they could make it to.  Not just "wait and see where we run out of gas".  But still, the "home" airport has major advantages for passengers who want to call a friend to come pick them up or whatever.  Or if there weren't any candidate airports where that airline had repair staff / facilities.  Or is this just a case of "don't mess around when you already have one emergency", and play it as safe as possible?  Since if something else went wrong, they could end up mid-nowhere.

Comment: @DanNeely: My initial thinking was: plane still flies, you only have a big problem when trying to land.  So why just waste fuel, instead of using it to get to NYC?  But then I realized the complication of the gear being stuck down adding drag, and other factors...  Is this worth asking as a separate question?

Comment: @PeterCordes If you can't find a duplicate, it would make a good question

Comment: @PeterCordes procedures aside, put yourself in the pilots' shoes. Your nosewheel jams, and you have no clue what caused that to happen. For all you know, engines are next. You're close to a major airport, but if you land the plane _now_ you'd be overweight and risk fire or an excursion, so you decide to fly in a pattern until you're light enough. Still, if the situation with your aircraft suddenly worsens, you'd very much want to keep open the option to land immediately, right?

Comment: @Mels: Ah yeah, that makes sense.  I was thinking that nose-wheel-stuck was known to be a problem that can just happen on some planes, and isn't usually just a symptom of a more serious problem.  But that's not a safe assumption, especially given the downside if you're wrong.  If you want to me to post a proper question so you can post the answer somewhere more people will see it, let me know. :P

Comment: Highly related [Why burn fuel at departure airport instead of flying to destination before emergency landing due to deflated tire?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23883/why-burn-fuel-at-departure-airport-instead-of-flying-to-destination-before-emerg), which was the 3rd google hit for `site:aviation.stackexchange.com nose gear stuck fly airport land`.  It's about the case where the gear isn't stuck down, but the accepted answer is basically the same: there might be other problems, so stay close to a good airport, like @Mels said.